# Deleting characters after based on index on a BigDecimal

Tags: java, indexing, substring, bigdecimal

I am trying to remove everything after index 9 (the three 0's at the end). I have tried using *substring* but cant seem to get it to work.

Code:

```
BigDecimal priceValue = 90.473426000;

// code to remove everything after index 9

System.out.println(priceValue);
```

Output Wanted:

```
90.473426
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want either https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros() or https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int) based on your requirements.  (updated with java 14, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not using `String.substring` for this as it only does a cosmetic adjustment for output.  Besides, there is a method in the `BigDecimal` class that does this for you [BigDecimal#stripTrailingZeros](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros()).

```
BigDecimal priceValue = new BigDecimal("90.473426000");
System.out.println(priceValue);
priceValue = priceValue.stripTrailingZeros();
System.out.println(priceValue);
```

Prints

```
90.473426000
90.473426
```